# Image magick (windows) - How do I perform batch resizing for several images type in a folder?

Tags: imagemagick

How do I perform batch-resizing for many images in a folder?

for example I have 4 images in folder C:\tried

```
image1.jpeg
image2.png
image3.bmp
image4.tiff
```

and I want to

```
 1. convert them to JPG
 2. resize them to 575px
 3. lower the quality of each image to 90%
 4. move them into different folder
 5. delete every picture that converted
```

**Can I do this using batch file (*.bat) in Windows?**

start from number 1,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow:

```
magick mogrify -path OUTPUTDIRECTORY -format JPEG -resize 575 -quality 90 *.tif *.jpg *.bmp
```

You'll have to delete them yourself.

Comment: it works, thank you, before this, I use convert, always failed, but this is so helpful :)